# How to get the date of the content initial published date?

Tags: kentico

In Kentico, is there a way to know the date the content was published for the first time? In the view_cms_tree_joined view there are fields called DocumentLastPublished and DocumentCreatedWhen but the latter is populated when the user save the content initially even if it's not published and the former is updated when the content is republished. Should I look at the workflowversionhistory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to look through the workflow history for that document and get the initial publish state. If you don't want to do that (might be pretty messy and lengthy) you could always add a field to the page type for an initial publish date which will allow someone to add that date or default to when it is saved and not allow it to be editable after it is saved by using a macro on the enabled property of that field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Brenden. Not all of our page types have the dedicated field for post date but it seems like adding one as much as possible is a best practice. I will try to look at the wofklow history for now and in the future I would recommend to add post date field.